# SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, keras

I am using my keras model to detect 2 categories using a modified tkinter program to that classifies butterfly species.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy
import cv2

import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("64x300-CNN.model")

classes = ["real", "fake"]

top=tk.Tk()
top.geometry('800x600')
top.title('Butterfly Classification')
top.configure(background='#CDCDCD')
label=Label(top,background='#CDCDCD', font=('arial',15,'bold'))
sign_image = Label(top)

def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 50  # 50 in txt-based
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # read in the image, convert to grayscale
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))  # resize image to match model's expected sizing
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)  # return the image with shaping that TF wants.

def classify(file_path):
    global label_packed
    new_array = cv2.imread(file_path, 1)
    pred = model.predict([prepare(new_array)])
    sign = classes[pred]
    print(sign)
    label.configure(foreground='#011638', text=sign)

def show_classify_button(file_path):
    classify_b=Button(top,text="Classify Image",
    command=lambda: classify(file_path),padx=10,pady=5)
    classify_b.configure(background='#364156', foreground='white',
    font=('arial',10,'bold'))
    classify_b.place(relx=0.79,rely=0.46)

def upload_image():
    try:
        file_path=filedialog.askopenfilename()
        uploaded=Image.open(file_path)
        uploaded.thumbnail(((top.winfo_width()/2.25),
        (top.winfo_height()/2.25)))
        im=ImageTk.PhotoImage(uploaded)
        sign_image.configure(image=im)
        sign_image.image=im
        label.configure(text='')
        show_classify_button(file_path)
    except:
        pass

upload=Button(top,text="Upload an image",command=upload_image,
  padx=10,pady=5)

upload.configure(background='#364156', foreground='white',
    font=('arial',10,'bold'))

upload.pack(side=BOTTOM,pady=50)
sign_image.pack(side=BOTTOM,expand=True)
label.pack(side=BOTTOM,expand=True)
heading = Label(top, text="Butterfly Classification",pady=20, font=('arial',20,'bold'))

heading.configure(background='#CDCDCD',foreground='#364156')
heading.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

and got this error

> SystemError:  returned NULL without setting
> an error

I have tried a fix from a similar question asked here but with no luck I think there is a problem when importing the image through tkinter and not through a file path?

> [Using cv2.imread: "<built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error", as if it can't open the picture or get the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123915/using-cv2-imread-built-in-function-imread-returned-null-without-setting-an-e)

full error message

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\1rock\anaconda3\envs\machL\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 1883, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "C:/Users/1rock/anaconda3/envs/machL/fly.py", line 36, in 
> command=lambda: classify(file_path),padx=10,pady=5)   File "C:/Users/1rock/anaconda3/envs/machL/fly.py", line 29, in classify
> pred = model.predict([prepare(new_array)])   File "C:/Users/1rock/anaconda3/envs/machL/fly.py", line 22, in prepare
> img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # read in the image, convert to grayscale SystemError:  returned NULL without setting an error
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: The two lines `new_array = cv2.imread(file_path, 1)` and `pred = model.predict([prepare(new_array)])` should be changed to `pred = model.predict([prepare(file_path)])`.

Comment: hiya thanks for the reply when I did that i got this error
`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1rock\anaconda3\envs\machL\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/1rock/anaconda3/envs/machL/fly.py", line 35, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: classify(file_path),padx=10,pady=5)
  File "C:/Users/1rock/anaconda3/envs/machL/fly.py", line 29, in classify
    sign = classes[pred]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: You should check what `pred` (returned by `model.predict()`) is.  As it is used as index to access `classes` (a list), it should be integer.

Comment: I checked using another code model.predict should only print out either 0 or 1

Comment: Did you check the type of `pred`? According to the official document, it is `numpy array`.

Comment: `[[0.]]
real`
that was the output

Comment: when i tried this code 
`prediction = model.predict([prepare(r'C:\Users\1rock\datasets\CamScanner 11-29-2020 20.08.54_7.jpg')])`

Comment: `print(prediction)`
`print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])])`

Comment: That is why you get the error.  `classes[pred]` expects `pred` is an integer.

Comment: ohhh sry Im new at this should i change datatype of classes[pred]?

Comment: Try `class[int(pred[0][0])]` (it is based on the output `[[0.]] real`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prepare function you implemented does the process of loading, resizing, reshaping images. The purpose of the function `cv2.imread` is to open an image from a given file path. But you fed the function `prepare(new_array)` where `new_array` is already the image itself, not the file path. I suggest two fixes, although both are conclusively equal.

Also, `model.predict` outputs the final layer in real numbers instead of integer-type class number. Therefore you must use `model.predict_classes` in this case. Also, because these functions default to batch mode, although you only feed a single image, you must assume the prediction to be an array, and index it.

First fix is to feed the file path and load the image inside the `prepare` function.

```
def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 50  # 50 in txt-based
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # read in the image, convert to grayscale
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))  # resize image to match model's expected sizing
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)  # return the image with shaping that TF wants.

def classify(file_path):
    global label_packed
    pred = model.predict_classes([prepare(file_path)])
    sign = classes[pred[0,0]]
    print(sign)
    label.configure(foreground='#011638', text=sign)
```

Next is to perform only reshaping in the `prepare` function.

```
def prepare(img_array):
    IMG_SIZE = 50  # 50 in txt-based
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))  # resize image to match model's expected sizing
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)  # return the image with shaping that TF wants.

def classify(file_path):
    global label_packed
    new_array = cv2.imread(file_path, 1)
    pred = model.predict_classes([prepare(new_array)])
    sign = classes[pred[0,0]]
    print(sign)
    label.configure(foreground='#011638', text=sign)
```

I would also like to say that this type of resizing process is very inefficient. What would be a solution for an input pipeline is the preprocessing layers developed inside Tensorflow. You can create a model acting as an input pipeline.

```
input_pipeline=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(h,w,..),
  tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing...
])
...
new_array=input_pipeline.predict(img_array)
```

or use `tf.image.resize`, since they can processes batches of images without an explicit loop, and provides more features that can be applied simply.

Comment: hiya thanks for the reply im pretty new at this please bear with me for the first fix how should I feed the file path and load the image because when I run the program there is a gui that ask me to load an image when I click it my folder opens up but when I try to input an image i get this error `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: In my understanding of your code, the user inputs the file path in `upload_image` and calls `show_classify_button` which again calls `classify`, which uses the `prepare` function for preprocessing the image. `file_path` is fed from `upload_image` to the `classify` function, but you fed the `prepare` function with the image itself, instead of the file path. My first fix is replacing the image with the file path.

Comment: In which line does the `TypeError` occur?

Comment: If the error occurs at `sign = classes[pred]` pls wait a moment I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @ISETHSGT tested it out, and it worked perfectly

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply sorry taking so long i checked the error was in sign = classes[pred] i changed file_path to `file_path=(r'C:\Users\1rock\datasets\CamScanner 11-29-2020 20.08.54_7.jpg')` and when I clicked upload image it sent out the image immediately withought me finding the file

Comment: unfortunately yes I still get this error `sign = classes[pred]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: @ISETHSGT Did you change the code to `pred = model.predict_classes([prepare(file_path)])` and `sign = classes[pred[0]]` instead of `sign = classes[pred]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227079/discussion-between-krenerd-and-iseths-gt).